# Rails Pg_Search stopped working with no code changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pg-search

I have a library management app with pg_search implemented; everything was working fine and all of the suddent it started to display all items on index but i didn't change anything regarding the feature.
I'll leave all pertaining code, please tell me if it's needed something more.
Thanks in advance.

> book.rb

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :loans
  belongs_to :category

  has_one_attached :photo

  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :author, presence: true

 

  include PgSearch::Model

  pg_search_scope :search_by_full_name, against: [:title, :author],
    using: {
      tsearch: {
        prefix: true
      }
    }

    def self.to_csv(options = {})
      CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
        csv << column_names
        all.each do |book|
          csv << book.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
        end
      end
    end

    #self.per_page = 12
end
```

> book_controller.rb

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
    if params[:term].present?
      @books = Book.search_by_full_name(params[:term])
      @books = policy_scope(Book)
    else
      @books = Book.paginate(page: params[:page])
      @books = policy_scope(Book) 
    end
    
  end

  def show
    @book = Book.find(params[:id])
    authorize @book
  end

  def new
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @book = Book.new
    @categories = Category.all.map{|c| [ c.name, c.id ] }
    authorize @book
  end

  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @book = Book.new(book_params)
    # @book.category_id = params[:category_id] 
    @book.user = @user
    authorize @book
    if @book.save
      redirect_to user_books_path
      flash[:notice] = 'Success. Your book was added to the Library'
    else
      render "new"
      flash[:notice] = 'Book not created. Please try again'

    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @book = Book.find(params[:id])
    @categories = Category.all.map{|c| [ c.name, c.id ] }
    authorize @book
  end

  def update
    @book = Book.find(params[:id])
    @book.category_id = params[:category_id]
    @book.update(book_params)
    authorize @book
    redirect_to user_book_path
  end

  def destroy
    @book = Book.find(params[:id])
    @book.destroy
    authorize @book
    redirect_to user_books_path
  end

  private

  def book_params
    params.require(:book).permit(:title, :author, :photo, :comments, :category_id)
  end
end
```

_book_search_bar.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag user_books_path(:user_id), method: :get, class: "search-bar" do %>
  <%= text_field_tag 'term', params[:term], placeholder: "Enter book or author" %>
  <br>
  <br>
  <%= submit_tag "SEARCH BOOK", class: "btn-main" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're just reassigning `@books = policy_scope(Book)` which will remove both the search scope and pagination.

```
def index
  if params[:term].present?
    @books = Book.search_by_full_name(params[:term])
  else
    @books = Book.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end
  @books = policy_scope(@books)
end
```

Instead of the class pass an actual scope to pundit or flip it upside down:

```
def index
  @books = policy_scope(Book).then do |scope|
    if params[:term].present?
      scope.search_by_full_name(params[:term])
    else
      scope.paginate(page: params[:page])
    end
  end
end
```

> stopped working with no code changed

Not likely. More likely is that the regressions were caused when implementing Pundit and there where no tests that detected it. Things don't happen magically.

Comment: Tks for the input... i tried your solution but it still didin't work; I have implemented pundit since the beginning and pg_search was working just fine with it, that's why i can figure it out.

Comment: "It didn't work" doesn't tell me anything. And I can really only take the code in the question into account as you haven't written anything about the actual methodology which is probably to blame. My advice is to write integration or functional tests with both the search param and without it and assert about which records are included.

Comment: i apreciate your help a lot, really... Maybe because i'm a "noobie", i couldn't find the best explanation for the problem... But when i said "it didn't worked" was that, the url shows the :term word searched and commited but the view index always gives the entire DB. But i'll take your advice and try to implement some tests